# Inconsistent recv() behavior

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, recv

Running a little internal CTF to teach people some computer security basics and I've run into a strange behavior. The following is the handle function of a forking TCP server. It is just a cute little buffer overflow demonstration (taken from CSAW CTF).

When testing, I only ever bothered sending it 4097 bytes worth of data, because that will successfully overflow into the `backdoor` variable. However, many of the participants decided to try to send exactly 4099 bytes and this doesn't actually work. I'm not entirely sure why.

In GDB, `recv`ing 4099 bytes works just fine, but otherwise it does not. I've spent a good amount of time debugging this now, as I'd like a good explanation for everybody as to why the service behaved as it did. Is it some sort of quirk with the `recv()` call or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

```
void handle(int fd)
{
  int backdoor = 0;
  char attack[4096];

  send(fd, greeting, strlen(greeting), 0);
  sleep(3);

  recv(fd, attack, 0x1003, 0);

  if (backdoor) 
  {
    dup2(fd, 0); dup2(fd, 1); dup2(fd, 2);
    char* argv[] = {"/bin/cat", "flag", NULL};
    execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
    exit(0);
  }

  send(fd, nope, strlen(nope), 0);
}
```

**Edit**
The executable was compiled with:

```
 clang -o backdoor backdoor.c -O0 -fno-stack-protector
```

I did not use different optimization settings for debugging / the live executable. I can run the following command:

```
python -c "print 'A'*4099" | nc <ip> <port>
```

and this will not work. I then attach to the running process via GDB (setting a breakpoint directly after the `recv` call) and run the above command again and it *does* work. I have repeated this multiple times with some variations, yet the same results.

Could it be something to do with the way that the OS handles queueing excess bytes sent to the socket? When I am sending 4099 bytes with the above command, I am actually sending 5000 (Python's `print` appends a newline implicitly). This means that `recv`'s newline gets truncated and is left for the next call to `recv` to clean up. Still can't figure out how GDB could influence this at all, but just a theory.

Comment: First thing, the behavior of this program will be erratic at best because you are not checking the return of send() and recv(), so it may well be that not all 4096 bytes is being sent.

Comment: I am not checking because it is irrelevant. I would have nothing to do with those values even if I did store them.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that your program behavior differs depending on whether or not you are using GDB? And if so, then GDB gives the "expected" behavior?

Comment: Sort of. Based on the code, I would expect any number of bytes received by this program in excess of 4096 to successfully overflow into the backdoor variable. Yet this is not the case when 4099 bytes (or anything in excess of this) is sent. However, in GDB, it behaves as expected. I realize that the GDB environment in terms of memory layout differs from the a process' standard environment, but this seems like a difference in how the recv() function is performing.

Answer (score 1):

> ... am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Yes, you are expecting undefined behaviour to be predictable. It isn't.

If you compile that function with `gcc`, using `-O3`, then you'll get a warning about exceeding the size of the receive buffer (but of course you already knew that); but you'll also get a binary which does not actually bother to check `backdoor`. If you use `clang`, you don't get the warning, but you get a binary which doesn't even allocate space for `backdoor`.

The reason is clear: modifying `backdoor` through a "backdoor" is undefined behaviour, and the compiler is under no obligation to do anything you might consider logical or predictable in the face of undefined behaviour. In particular, it's allowed to assume that the undefined behaviour never happens. Since no valid program could mutate `backdoor`, the compiler is allowed to assume that `backdoor` never gets mutated, and hence it can ditch the code inside the `if` block as unreachable.

You don't mention how you're compiling this program, but if you're compiling without optimization to use `gdb` and with optimisation when you don't plan to use `gdb`, then you should not be surprised that undefined behaviour is handled differently. On the other hand, even if you are compiling the program with the same compiler and options in both cases, you still shouldn't be surprised, since undefined behaviour is, as it says, undefined.

Declaring `backdoor` as `volatile` *might* prevent the optimization. Although that's hardly the point, is it?

---

Note: I'm using gcc version 4.8.1 and clang version 3.4. Different versions (and even different builds) might have different results.

Comment: `backdoor` is _not_ optimized out in the OP's program, because the OP clearly states that the exploit works when only 4097 bytes are sent to it.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: *assuming* OP consistently uses the same compiler options. Also, we don't know (1) what bytes are being transmitted or (2) whether the compiler has decided to only check one byte of `backdoor`, or (3) what the phase of the moon was at the time the program was run.

Comment: I just edited the post to explain my compiler options and hopefully give a bit more insight into the scenario. I understand that you can't necessarily account for compiler optimization, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: @user3291189: with clang 3.4 and the options you specify, `attack` is at stack offset -4112 and `backdoor` is at -8, so you'd need 4105 bytes to reach overrun. I think this is because the current ABI requires arrays like `attack` to be 16-byte aligned. What version of clang do you use?

Comment: Interesting. I am using clang 3.4. But this actually confused things a bit more, as I can consistently trigger the exploit with less than that. I will go peek at the stack offsets within my own binary and see what that looks like.

Comment: @user3291189: perhaps you are on a different platform. Or your default options include something which mine don't. (My platform is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.)

Comment: @user3291189: also, I cannot reproduce the issue with either -m32 or -m64. Are you perhaps using windows?

Comment: I have tried on both OS X (my primary operating system) and an Arch Linux VM. The executable used in the competition was compiled on said VM.